# How do I release images and avoid outOfMemory exc-n when navigating back and forth between activities[android]

Tags: android, out-of-memory, heap-memory, android-memory

I have a children tale  app - 18 pages, each page is an activity with a background image, short story and **sound for every word**(textView) in a story, and some animations.

I notice, when i go to next page, the memory is consumed;

it is also consumed when i go **back to previous page(activity)!** I get outOfMemory exception when the app reaches about 182MB usage - this can happen anytime.

[image: r]

- How do I release images if the image is a background for
  RelativeLayout in every page ?
- every time i navigate to next page, the previous is destroyed -
  should not the images it loads be released from memory as well?

  ```
  public class Page8 extends Activity{
  ImageView forward ;
  ImageView backward ;
  RelativeLayout main ;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.page8);
  forward = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.to_page_9);
  backward = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.to_page_7);
  forward.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) return false;
          Intent intent = new Intent(Page8.this, Page9.class);
          startActivity(intent);
          return true;
      }
  });
  backward.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) return false;
          Intent intent = new Intent(Page8.this, Page7.class);
          startActivity(intent);
          return true;
      }
  });
  }
     @Override
     public void onStop(){
     main = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main) ;
     main.releaseMemory()?;

    }
   }
  ```

Comment: how you are loading image in the ImageView? are you using any image loader library?

Comment: @dhuma1981, no i just do in xml , src = "@drawable/..."

Comment: Don't do that, use any image loader library, they will take care of the memory issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have HD images, you should optimize images and scale down them.

Comment: how do i scale them down? you mean make them exactly same pixel size as my tablet?

Comment: You should check device screen size's, as per screen size height width with keeping your image aspect ratio you can scale down images dynamically, do not add them in xml, add them in code, check out this link to optimize bitmaps, http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html